# How to convert javascript fill table to fill form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

My script calculates the price and shows the results in the table. I want to see that in the form which I can submit. Here is JavaScript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function update(){
var sum = 0;
$("#calculator > tbody > tr").each(function(){

var amount = parseFloat($(this).find("td").eq(1).find('input').val());
var value = $(this).find("td:eq(2)");
var price = $(this).find("td:eq(0)");

if (amount > 0 && amount < 501) {
price.text(0.37);
} else 
if (amount > 500 && amount < 3001) {
price.text(0.32);
} else 
if (amount > 3000 && amount < 6001) {
price.text(0.25);
} else 
if (amount > 6000 && amount < 10001) {
price.text(0.21);
} else 
if (amount > 10000) {
price.text(parseFloat(0.20).toFixed(2));
}

var _price = parseFloat(price.text());    

if (amount > 0 && amount !== undefined ) {
value.text(parseFloat(_price*amount).toFixed(2));
sum += _price*amount;
} else {
value.text(0);
}

});
$("#summary").text(parseFloat(sum).toFixed(2));
}
$(document).ready(function(){
update();
$("#calculator input").keyup(function(){
update();
});
});

</script>
```

And this is the table code in html

```
<table id="calculator" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><p align="right">Price</p></th>
            <th><p align="center">Amount</p></th>
            <th><p align="left">Value</p></th>
        </tr>
    </thead> 

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"></td>
            <td align="center"><input style="width:50px;" type="text" /></td>
            <td align="left"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

After fill Amount the script counts Value using price with rules. Please help me with convert that to do it not in the table but in the form.

```
<form id="transfer">

    <input class="text" id="price" type="text" value="" />
    <input class="text" id="amount" type="text" value="" />
    <input class="text" id="value" type="text" value="" />

</form>
```

Comment: i transfer the table value to form : http://jsfiddle.net/y9b1t41s/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have one more question. How to set variable in PHP with value from amount field?